# React Admin Input-components always add some extra space for helperText

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

Recently React Admin input components started to add extra space below in order to display helperText (if provided). But it seems that it is impossible to avoid this behaviour by added `helperText={false}` as it is recommended, e.g.:

`<TextInput source="myField" helperText={false} />`

It always displays some extra space no matter if I pass "false" as value to the `heplerText` prop or not.

I'm on React Admin version 3.2.3 now.

In RA's `TextInput` component we can see this code:

```
        helperText={ // <-- goes to MUI TextField
            <InputHelperText
                touched={touched}
                error={error}
                helperText={helperText} // <-- goes to RA InputHelperText
            />
        }
```

If the value of `InputHelperText` component's `helperText` prop is equal to false then `InputHelperText` renders nothing (returns null in its render function).
But the value of `heplerText` prop that goes to underlying MaterialUI `TextField` is never null nor undefined, even if I pass "false": it is always an `InputHelperText` component, which just may or may not render something.

MaterialUI TextField component, in turn, analyses its `heplerText` prop:

```
  const helperTextId = helperText && id ? `${id}-helper-text` : undefined; // <-- helperText from TextInput

  ...

  {helperText && (
    <FormHelperText id={helperTextId} {...FormHelperTextProps}>
      {helperText}
    </FormHelperText>
  )}
```

Since `helperText` is never null nor undefined, it will always render `FormHelperText`, perhaps with an empty `helperText`.

If I change the RA `TextInput` component's code like that:

```
        helperText={helperText && touched && error ?
            <InputHelperText
              touched={touched}
              error={error}
              helperText={helperText}
            /> : null
```

everything works fine: no extra space is added since the value of `helperText` (passed to the underlying MUI `TextField`) is indeed null when the value of `TextInput` component's `helperText` prop is equal to false.

Am I missing something or it is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/4364

A questionable feature.

Comment: The problem is that "heplerText={false}" doesn't work, above it is described why. My question is not about this "feature's" default behaviour, but about how to avoid it with "helperText={false}" and why it is broken.

Comment: If you read the comments in the linked issue carefully, the owner of `react-admin` states that:

`As for disabling helperText if you don't use validation, this is a feature we can add ...`

This means that in the future, `react-admin` may provide the feature you are looking for to send `false` to the `helperText` attribute. For right now, there is no way to opt-out of this feature, short of overriding `react-admin` core code, as you have demonstrated.

Comment: And if you carefully read [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4425),
this one, in particular:

`we chose to have working features and a less compact ui by default - letting you opting in to a compact UI with helperText={false}.`

and examine the source code, you'll see that this feature has been already implemented, this comment has been made after the one you refer to.
The purpose of the code snippets I mentioned in the original question is clear, but it doesn't work though. So I'm trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong or it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As of react-admin v4.3(+), passing a props `helperText={false}` to `<TextInput/>` does remove the extra space.

Example:

```
<TextInput source="meta.og.description" helperText={false} />
```